# IIS Reverse Proxy: Too Many Redirects and Header Code of 302

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, headers

[This is a cross post from ESRI's GIS site; I am not getting any luck there]

I have not been able to find step by step directions for ArcGIS for Portal and Reverse Proxy which uses IIS as a server. I have a setup in place which mostly work but fails at one critical point. Here's the setup:

1) Reverse Proxy Server (Windows) with static IP address accessible from the outside (only ports 80/443 allowed in).

2) An internal machine ('GIS') which has ArcGIS for Portal and Server installed along with their respective Web Adaptors ('portal' and 'arcgis' respectively).

3) The Portal also has WebContextURL of like 'https://gis.mydomain.com/portal'

4) The RP server has a couple of URL Rewrite entries--basically, direct to Server Farm which has the 'GIS' machine.

5) A proper SSL certificate is install as gis.mydomain.com in the IIS of both the RP server and the 'GIS' server.

So far this setup works great: I am able to access all content from the outside, such as https://gis.mydomain.com/portal/home and Gallery etc. But clicking on the Signup link in the Portal home page generates a browser error: Too Many Redirects (Header of 302). So the header being passed backed from the internal machine is 302 instead of 200.

I don't know what's happening. Maybe some extra security comes in picture when the signup.html page is called?

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You might at least trace what IIS rewrites, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules then the actual culprit should be revealed.

Comment: Thank you. I know that the internal server's IIS returns the signup.html page repeatedly in the logs with 302 headers--and so that gets passed back onto the Reverse Proxy's IIS server.